# Word problem: increasing time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey guys I was wondering how would this word problem be solved:

A guy walks for 5kms per hour. The day has 8 hours.Every day the hours of the day become 1 more.How many hours did he walked for 10 days.

Now this is not a real world scenario but I was wondering how the one hour increase each day could be evaluated in an expression? Can somebody help me?

Comment: 5*8 + 5*9 + ... + 5*(8+10-1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem as follows, where $d$ is the number of days.

The first day, he walked 5km for 8 hours, so $5\cdot8$

The second day, he walked 5km for 9 hours, so $5\cdot9$

So on and so forth.

In general, evaluate the sum $$\sum_{d=0}^9 5(8+d)$$

So, that is to say, evaluate the sum by adding 1 to 8 for each new day. Then multiply by 5.

Or you can add $8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17 = 125$ and then just multiply by 5 to get $625$ km

Comment: Yes thank you i was actually looking for the arithmetic progression, but i never knew that :D thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1st day : $5X8$

2nd day : $5X9$

.
.
.

10th day : $5X17$

You need to add them. take 5 common. Are you familiar with sum of an $AP$?

Comment: aha thank you i was actually searching exactly for the sum of an AP..i was not familiar with this.Thank you!